Error: mkdir Cannot Create a File When That File Already Exists in Docker with VS Code Dev Containers
I'm looking for solutions or guidance to resolve this error. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
To be honest, it is disaster for past two days to fix it.
I'm encountering an issue while running Docker on Windows 10 with VS Code's devcontainer.
Below is the error stacktrace. The error happens even if I re-install and setup from start.
Error response from daemon: mkdir c:\Users\gdla\uap: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
[13507 ms] Error: Command failed: docker-compose --project-name wld-dbt-main_devcontainer -f c:\Users\gdla\it_uap\wld-dbt-main\.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml -f c:\Users\gdla\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1717757114585.yml -f c:\Users\gdla\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1717757120739-15a6496d-fd1d-4ce5-bb30-8c9c26b833e2.yml up -d
[13507 ms]     at QtA (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:429:3355)
[13507 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[13507 ms]     at async utA (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:409:3506)
[13507 ms]     at async KtA (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:3865)
[13507 ms]     at async eB (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:4807)
[13507 ms]     at async hrA (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13373)
[13507 ms]     at async lrA (c:\Users\gdla\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.369.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13114)
[13519 ms] Exit code 1

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Docker Desktop Version: 4.31.0
VS Code Version: Latest with Remote - Containers extension

If you need more inputs, I can provide.

It looks like the error points out that c:\Users\gdla\uap already exists in your directory. Have you tried removing the directory first then retry?

yes. I tried in this way but its same as usual.
